# VF Load variable from controller

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have custom controller and I pass data from VF to controller and it works.
However, when I try to use this variable in controller at VF, I cannot.

Why is this happening?
VF Page

```
<apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction name="setCenter" action="{!setParam}" reRender="resultPanel" status="myStatus">
                <apex:param name="firstparam" assignTo="{!currentCenter}" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:form>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn_none").click(function(){
                    setCenter($(this).attr("title"));
                    alert('{!currentCenter}');  // Cannot get Value.      
            });
        </script>
```

Controller

```
public String currentCenter {get; set;}
public PageReference setParam(){
    PageReference pg;
    System.debug('setParam()' + currentCenter); // Debug get value successfully.

    return null;
}
```

Add.

```
<div class="btn_none" id="center" title="NYC">
     NYC
</div>
```

Comment: When you click this button .btn_none. Did you rerender the JS section?

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean.
Its, in document.ready and there is no other code

If you have any clue, please share with me

Comment: `$(".btn_none").click` on click event you are displaying alert. So you must have a button. Wher is `resultPanel`?

Comment: I updated question, and there is no resultPanel. I didn't use reRender attr.

Comment: You need to use rerender here to get the updated value. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to rerender the form

you need to use `oncomplete="onCompleteHandler()"` event of action function.
onCompleteHandler is a JS function inside you can have alert statement `alert('{!currentCenter}')`

like

```
<apex:actionFunction name="setCenter" action="{!setParam}" reRender="myform" status="myStatus" oncomplete="onCompleteHandler()">
        <apex:param name="firstparam" assignTo="{!currentCenter}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Put your script in the form. Give some id to form, and rerender that form by putting its id in `reRender` attribute of action function. See Below Code

```
    <apex:form id="myform">
    <!-- ... -->

    <apex:actionFunction name="setCenter" action="{!setParam}" reRender="myform" status="myStatus">
        <apex:param name="firstparam" assignTo="{!currentCenter}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Also If you have put your script in any outputpanel you can rerender that specifically by giving id of that particular outputpanel. In that case no need to rerender whole form.

Comment: Thanks Rahul.
I tried what you suggested and still it doesn't work. I just use form for warping actionFunction Only.

I don't need any rendering change. I just want to see value alert is poped well from Controller. For doing this, I need to consider reRender attr?

Comment: yes, try putting script into the form

Comment: Wonderful! it works! Could you please explain the reason that script need to be loacted in form?

+ when I ckick button at the first time, it doesn't show me value, but I try again, it works. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because It refresh part of page in particular form/outputpanel, and you get updated values from controller. Also one thing I forgot instead of this you can use `oncomple` event of action function, in this case you dont need to double click on the button

Comment: check updated answer!

Comment: Okay! I will try tro follow your second guide.
+
After broaden apex:form area, my another jqeury, .show function doesn't work. is there any clue?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Hi rahul. I will post another question, and then invite you in that questions!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you possible, please check this another post, 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241605/jquery-called-several-times-in-vf